# Creating custom ISO on CentOS results in dracut-initqueue timeout

Tags: linux, centos, iso

I'm able spin up the stock CentOS 7.7 ISO onto a virtual machine (and on a USB drive) just fine, but when I try to make a custom ISO directly from the stock ISO, I'm at a roadblock.

After the initial choice to `Install CentOS`, the system hangs at `Starting dracut initqueue hook...`, and then repeats `initqueue[696]: Warning: dracut-initqueue timeout - starting timeout scripts` until it finally says `Could not boot.` and then `/dev/root does not exist`, after which it goes to a Dracut Emergency Shell.

I'm following the steps I've seen like this:

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/mydrive
sudo mount -o loop ~user/CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1908.iso /media/mydrive
mkdir ~/customiso
sudo rsync -av /media/mydrive ~/customiso
cd ~/customiso
sudo genisoimage -o ../centoscustom.iso -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -J -R -v -T -V 'centos custom' .
```

(also used mkisofs instead of genisoimage, to no satisfaction)

It always fails at that same point after choice to install. I've even messed around with isolinux.cfg to make the `append` line match the filename, so

`append inird=inird.img inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=centoscustom quiet`

I'm trying to put some kickstart actions into a custom ISO of CentOS 7.7. I initially thought I was something related to the USB making or the ks.cfg file, but I've regressed to just trying to get a straight copy of the stock ISO working first.

Comment: I don't believe that you tried `mkisofs` as those OSS hostile distros that ship `genisoimage` make `mkisokfs` a link to `genisoimage` instead of installing the rel program. BTW: if you like help, you should describe your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out. The 2 things that need to match each other in the `genisoimage` command and `isolinux.cfg` file are stated as `THISNEEDSTOMATCH`:

`genisoimage -o ../centoscustom.iso -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -J -R -v -T -V 'THISNEEDSTOMATCH' .`

`append inird=inird.img inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=THISNEEDSTOMATCH quiet`

Comment: Please do not use `genisoimage`, as it creates defective filesystem images. `genisoimage` is a fork from a `mkisofs` from 2004 with plenty of Debian specific bugs added. The original `mkisofs` meanwhile fixed bugs and evolved a lot while `genisoimage` is dead since 2005. Check http://schilytools.sf.net

Answer (score 1):

I just struggled with this very issue (or, same symptoms, rather). Turned out I had actually forgotten to to include the entire `images/install.img` which, surprise, surprise, means the installer has trouble finding stage2.

mkisofs/genisoimage just blindly includes whatever is in the "staging area" directory.

In short, you need both isolinux and install.img to succeed. The way I resolved things was to loopmount the stock image and inspect it.

For reference, the entire thing goes something like this (substitute a suitable mirror yourself.)

```
mkdir iso
rsync -av rsync://mirrors.dotsrc.org/centos/8.2.2004/BaseOS/x86_64/os/isolinux ./iso/
rsync -av rsync://mirrors.dotsrc.org/centos/8.2.2004/BaseOS/x86_64/os/images/*.img ./iso/images/
cp my_custom_isolinux.cfg iso/isolinux/isolinux.cfg #Optional
cp my_custom_splash.png iso/isolinux/splash.png #Optional
cd iso && mkisofs -o ../qeyeboot8.iso -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -V "CentOS-8-2-2004-x86_64-dvd" -R -J -v -T .
isohybrid ../qeyeboot8.iso #Optional, allows the image to also be booted from USB
```